# Android : automate SVG import

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, android-drawable

We have a legacy Android project using drawables in the respective drawable folders for mdpi, hdpi, etc., We are planning to remove the PNG files and transition to SVG. The SVG Import UI described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html) creates the drawables xml from the svg. Is there a way to run this tool from command line so that we can automate the conversion from SVG to Android Drawable.xml format. We have a lot of files, so doing it manually is tedious. (Alternatively, if this is not possible, I will be writing a script to convert from SVG to Android Drawable.xml format. If such a tool already exists it will be very helpful.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The converter code from Android Studio can be found here:

[SVG2Vector.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/sdk-common/src/main/java/com/android/ide/common/vectordrawable/Svg2Vector.java)

It should be fairly easy to extract it and turn it into a command line utility.

Answer (score 8):

Android Studio version 3.4 added the Resource Manager tool, which lets you bulk import SVGs and convert them into vector drawables in one go.

1. `Tools` → `Resource Manager`
2. Select the `Drawable` tab
3. Click the `+` button in the top left corner
4. Select `Import Drawables`

There you can select all the files you want to import at once.
More details [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/resource-manager).

Answer (score 3):

Look at this tool from the Android SDK source base:
https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2018/11/android-studio-svg-to-vector-cli.html

You can download a compiled version, or compile it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Found an online tool : http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/ 
If there is a Android provided command line tool, it will be very helpful in terms of automating via scripts.